# In @Entity class i need to specify a value to be not null along with checking a regexp match if it comes with a value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Column(name = "last_name", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = true)
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]+", message = "invalid last name")
private String lastName;
```

I would like to get suggestion on setting value to default `null` and apply pattern match only value present.

Comment: ok. And what prevent you from doing that?

Comment: It seems that your code is correct, and it solves the task. Or did you encounter any problems when using it?

Comment: yes the problem is ,i cant proceed to save others values by keeping this field as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this from your code

```
nullable = true
```